# ng serve command, hanging the entire system

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying to run the angular application with the command `ng serve`. The application is compiling successfully but while running the application on browser, the system is hanging out. I am not sure about why is this happening.

Here is package.json

```
{
    "name": "parking-web",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~11.2.8",
 "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.8",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/localize": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/material": "^11.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.8",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.8",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.0",
"@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
"@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.2",
"@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.2",
"angular-page-loader": "^1.0.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"bootstrap-float-label": "^3.0.1",
"bootstrap4-toggle": "^3.6.1",
"bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
"crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"sweetalert2": "^10.16.7",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"underscore": "^1.13.1",
"zone.js": "~0.11.3"
},
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.7",
"@angular/cli": "~11.2.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.8",
"@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@types/underscore": "^1.11.2",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.1.5"
 }
}
```

Could someone please help me out.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: The system got hanged out before seeing the browser console. I tried running the same application in chrome , firefox and in edge. The same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling "ng serve --verbose" you could find helpful information. Check also the processes of your OS using top under Linux / MacOS or task manager on Windows after running ng serve to see which process is blocking the system and why (CPU use 100%? RAM almost full?)

Comment: Yes, the CPU usage and RAM is filling to 100%.. I added --verbose flag and I am seeing some warnings , do I need to consider those

Comment: Which process is consuming the resources? Can you add the warnings here please? Thanks! I would also try to run it on a docker container or other PC / Laptop and check if you have the same behavior